# Setup Federation of Windows AD in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, amazon-iam, adfs2.0

I am new to AWS i am trying to federate aws access with my active directory. So far i have created a Windows Server 2008 [ec2 instance] in a VPC on aws. I have installed AD, DNS, ADFS. I followed all the steps mentioned in this link --> http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx71TWXXJ3UI14/Enabling-Federation-to-AWS-using-Windows-Active-Directory-ADFS-and-SAML-2-0

I was successful in creating the Windows active directory but i am not able to access it outside the VM. I have created a elastic ip and associated it with that instance as well, since it is created in a VPC.

My requirement is to access the aws management console with my AD details in place of IAM.I am struck with this i don't know where to go from here.

I am very new to AWS, sorry if my terms are wrong.. Kindly help me with this.

Comment: Did you wanted setup federation AWS with AD when you got AD inside same AWS EC2? And do you wanna will get access from this EC2 instance to the itself IAM? Right?

Comment: Yes that's what i mean

Comment: Then I recommend you find out about AWS Roles. Another worlds you have to allowed your EC2 instance access to IAM space.